# Need help catching firebase user permission error on flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I am really confused about this permission-denied exception that is being thrown but I cannot catch it no matter what I do.

Here is my function:

```
Future<bool> uploadDataToStorage(String user, String jsonData) async {
  try {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final formatter = DateFormat.yMMMMd().add_jm();
    final formattedDateTime = formatter.format(now);

    final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    final Reference storageRef =
        storage.ref().child('backup/${user}_backup.json');

    FirebaseStorage.instance.setMaxUploadRetryTime(Duration(seconds: 2));

    Uint8List data = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(jsonData));
    final UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putData(data);

    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    print('Data upload error: $error');
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is what shows up in the console

```
E/StorageException(18561): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(18561): User does not have permission to access this object.
E/StorageException(18561):  Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
E/StorageException(18561): The server has terminated the upload session
E/StorageException(18561): java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload 
session
E/StorageException(18561):  at 
com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(UploadTask.java:359)
E/StorageException(18561):  at 
com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(UploadTask.java:325)
....continues..
```

I am just not able to catch this. I am denying perms on purpose from firebase just to handle this error.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you go to IAM / roles firebase and attached to the service account you are using and adjusted the permission you need to run your script ?

Comment: Yes as I mentioned everything is already set up. I am able to upload and download files. I just want to catch this exception because my app shows that file successfully uploaded despite this error being thrown but not caught.

Comment: Firestore and Cloud Storage for Firebase (often referred to as Firebase Storage) as two different product. Going forward, please use the tags for the product that you actually use in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're not waiting for the `uploadTask` to complete, so you `return true;` before it has a chance to succeed or fail.

Try this

```
await storageRef.putData(data);
```

This is exactly what the code samples in the Firebase documentation on [uploading files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files#upload_from_a_file) also do, so I recommend keeping that handy.

Comment: The situation is quite strange. If I try await it basically waits forever. So the infinite progress bar I have basically shows forever. If I don’t do await then it tells me it was successful but in logs the errors exception prints out.

Comment: As said: if you don't use await (or `then()` and `catch()`) you return `true` before the operation complete. So that return value is meaningless. If you use `await`, the failure should raise an exception - although I haven't tried that in a while.

Comment: I tried 

`await storageRef.putData(data).then((p0) => print("THE RESULT: " + p0.toString())).catchError((err) => print("THE RESULT: " + err.toString()));;`

But ya sadly it just awaits forever.